# How get message that the pattern or the password written wrong

Tags: java, android

i want a function that count or even get that the password or the pattern of the mobile is written wrong ?

```
public int number_of_times ()
```

`}
return times;
}`

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible if you use the device administration APIs. Specifically, you need:

- a `DeviceAdminReceiver` subclass, appropriately registered in the manifest, where you would find out about password failures
- device admin metadata, indicating that you wanted to be informed about device admin failures
- a UI that helps the user go into the Settings app and enable your app as a device administrator

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DeviceAdmin/PasswordEnforcer) demonstrates all of that, as part of a slightly larger sample that also sets password quality requirements.

Of note, my `AdminReceiver`'s element in the manifest requests to be informed about password failures, by including the `ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED` action in my `<intent-filter>`:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED"/>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Also, my device admin metadata (`res/xml/device_admin.xml`) includes the `<watch-login/>` policy:

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password/>

        <watch-login/>
    </uses-policies>

</device-admin>
```

In addition, my `AdminReceiver` is a subclass of `DeviceAdminReceiver` and overrides `onPasswordFailed()`, to find out about failures:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2013 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.pwenforce;

import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onEnabled(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName cn=new ComponentName(ctxt, AdminReceiver.class);
    DevicePolicyManager mgr=
        (DevicePolicyManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

    mgr.setPasswordQuality(cn,
                           DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHANUMERIC);

    onPasswordChanged(ctxt, intent);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPasswordChanged(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
    DevicePolicyManager mgr=
        (DevicePolicyManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    int msgId;

    if (mgr.isActivePasswordSufficient()) {
      msgId=R.string.compliant;
    }
    else {
      msgId=R.string.not_compliant;
    }

    Toast.makeText(ctxt, msgId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPasswordFailed(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(ctxt, R.string.password_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
         .show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPasswordSucceeded(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(ctxt, R.string.password_success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
         .show();
  }
}
```